# Firebase plans and usage quotas

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I want to test Firebase analytics to monitor my app but i'm a little concerned about the free mode. Am I obligated to use Firebase storage, real time database, hosting and all that? or can I have my own and use Firebase just for analytics?

What I fear is giving up my current infra structure and end up with the app turned off during release because it got too many access or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Firebase Analytics without using any of the other Firebase features. Firebase Analytics is free and unlimited.